# Windows 10, add SMB drive located on External network

Tags: windows, internet, smb

I have created a SMB share on my Windows 10 PC. I have forwarded the nesecary ports on my router to allow outside acces to the server.

From my mac (On other network) i can connect to the server no problem (Through the Connect to server window in finder), and it works great. Now i am trying to add the drive to another windows laptop, that is not on the same network. How do i add this, using the options under "This Pc" -> "Map Network Drive" i can connect, but i cannot use the Username and password i have setup. Do i need to add something before the username?

I hope someone can help me on this.

EDIT:

I have tried using the domain name, and it does not work eiter.
It wasd allready as the domain at first, but i tried anyway. 
[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YE0o.png)

Answer (score 1):

For the username, try: hostname\username

hostname = the computer name of the computer that has the network share.  To get the computer name to the computer that has the share and right click on the Start Menu and select System.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it didn't work (Piturec added to original post)

Comment: Try connection via `net use <drive_letter> \\path\to\device\share /user:<username>`. You should then be prompted for a password. If nothing else it should give you some sort of useful error.

Comment: I was never able to get SMB works on "external" network even when opening all ports requested. The only way I could get it to work was via VPN. Also keep in mind SMB is not secure at all so I can not recommend using SMB over internet even if you are able to make it work.